# Get insert statement query

Tags: mysql

Is there a way to get the insert statements for a table via some query in MySql?

for  ex: if the table name is Cards,which has 5 rows, i need to get the insert statements for that particular table.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a "mysqldump" which will backup the database to a file. That file will include all off the insert statements with data.

Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

Doug's right. You can use `mysqldump`. But you can refine it a bit and **only write out the scripts for the tables that you want**. [This explains how](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html).